# call another class in dll file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have my own class inside the file name "Render.h" and the class implementation is inside the 
"Render.cpp".Now I want to access or call this class (Render.cpp) in my DLL file.

I want the file "Load .h" which is a dll file to recognize this class "Render.h".

What should I do? Please do help me.(in c ++)

Answer (score 0):

include the Render.h into Load.h (or Load.cpp depending on your context) and include Render.cpp in the DLL project.

Comment: Yes, but here is no need to yell !

Comment: Whoops - sorry @Raveline apparently I can't lead a sentence with #include - edited